# Xamarin forms: How to change the listview activity spinner color

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, renderer, custom-renderer

How can I change the color of the activity indicator spinner for the Xamarin.Forms.ListView, specifically for iOS?

I found [some](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92729/refresh-spinner-color) [posts](https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/24/xamarin-tips-xamarin-forms-ios-listview-refresh-spinner-color/) regarding the issue, but custom renderers are way too advanced for me at this point, I can't really make any sense out of them yet.

Using the second link I created the class in the iOS project with the given code, and a class in the PCL project, so that it can be referenced from my XAML view:

```
namespace spinnerTest
{
    public class ColoredRefreshListView : ListView
    {
    }
}
```

The code I found, for convenience:

```
public class ColoredRefreshListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var vc = ((UITableViewController)ViewController);

        if (vc?.RefreshControl != null)
            vc.RefreshControl.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(135, 200, 21);
    }
}
```

While the XAML compiles successfully using the custom control, the color doesn't change.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution, but your approach is working only when you pull to refresh (not on first load).

Only the namespace attribute for renderer is missing:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(ColoredRefreshListViewRenderer))]
namespace Test.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ColoredRefreshListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           var vc = ((UITableViewController)ViewController);

           if (vc?.RefreshControl != null)
               vc.RefreshControl.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(135, 200, 21);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you want to apply your renderer as default for `ListView`, you have to specify `ListView` type in `ExportRender(<type>)`. Instead use your defined base type (`ColoredRefreshListView` in your example), but in this case, you have to declare explicitly this type in XAML, and not only `ListView` base type.

Comment: Woah, this is a blast from the past.
IIRC, I pretty much did what you are describing and used it as a custom control (not default).

I also may be very mistaken, but I think that it was fixed in a later Forms version.